# Ajax sending to server body is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, vote

I'm Making a simple voting system using ajax.

here's the code...

```js
// Receving The Votes
app.post('/submitvote', (req, res) => {
    // req.body, body is undefined
    // should be: { choice: 2 }, 2 is just an example
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

This code saves vote from the judge's into a variable just for testing.
But The body(where the choice is) is undefined

let's look at the client side...

```js
var picked = 0

function voteto(plr) {
    +plr;
    picked = plr;
    console.log(`Picked Player #${plr}`)
    if (plr == 1) {
        document.getElementById('plr1').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('plr1').style.backgroundColor = 'darkblue';
    }

    if (plr == 2) {
        document.getElementById('plr2').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('plr2').style.backgroundColor = 'darkblue';
    }

    if (plr == 3) {
        document.getElementById('plr3').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('plr3').style.backgroundColor = 'darkblue';
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        console.log("Sending Data");
        $.post("/submitvote", {
            choice: picked,
        });
    });
});
```

The `voteto` function is a selector for the vote.

I just send the `picked` variable in the `choice` parameter(I don't know what would you call that). I didn't make a callback since it's just saving it.

But The Thing Is The Body is undefined. Why?

Comment: I imagine you're simply missing `app.use(express.urlencoded())`

Comment: ... and / or you should be preventing the default click event action... `$("#submit").on("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); /* the rest of your code */ })`

Comment: @Phil I don't have the ```app.use(express.urlencoded())``` so that maybe the cause of the problem. And I'll try also to prevent the default click event action later.

Answer (score 0):

Add `app.use(express.urlencoded())` in the app.js(entry). This Works For Me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).